# SharedPreferences should remember the content of the TextView when it returns to MainActivity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a situation where there is a TextView in MainActivity with some textual content. However, when I go from MainActivity to SecondActivity and return to MainActivity again, the text contained in TextView is lost. I tried to solve this with the help of SharedPreferences and I wrote the code. **SharedPreferences does not save when I return from SecondActivity.** I really do not see where I am making a problem in this code and I ask your help.

```
private void SavePreferences(String key, String value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}

private void LoadPreferences()
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String textstorage = sharedPreferences.getString("TEXT", "");
    mytext.setText(textstorage);

}
```

Comment: Please provide a logcat so we can see what the error is

Comment: **How are you returning from Second Activity to Main Activity**, because not neccessary onCreate would be called when you comeback from second activity to main activity. Also if you are getting error please provide complete stacktrace. in question.

Comment: For your example that you posted here, I suggest using two buttons: one that calls `SavePreferences()` and one that calls `LoadPreferences()`. This will help you isolate the problem. Once you have done that, test them both by clicking each button. Then come back and describe what happens. Be sure to include any error messages from your logcat if there are any.

Comment: Pro tip: you can improve your code example here by adding `class ??? extends Activity {}` around the example code. This will help make it clear where your code belongs. It also gives us a class name that we can refer to when talking about your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call  LoadPreferences() in onResume() because onCreate() won't be called when you return back from Second Activity

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LoadPreferences();
}
```

Comment: Just call your SavePreferences method in onCreate and  pass empty string for value like : SavePreferences("TEXT", "")

Answer (score 0):

you need to give name to your preference try below code:`SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE).edit()
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.apply();
    editor.commit(); // you can omit this, i use this one`

and to get it back `SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    String textstorage = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "default value"); // default value will be alternate value if you string is not found
    mytext.setText(textstorage);`